# Why are all irq disabled for retarget write on STM32?

Tags: c, arm, embedded, stm32, irq

I am looking at the following function which retargets stdout to UART in the STM32 Std peripheral library.

```
int _write(int fd, char *ptr, int len) {
  uint32_t primask = __get_PRIMASK();
  __disable_irq();

  for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
    while (USART_GetFlagStatus(RETARGET_CFG_UART, USART_FLAG_TXE) == RESET) {
    }
    USART_SendData(RETARGET_CFG_UART, (uint8_t) * (ptr + i));
  }

  if (!primask) {
    __enable_irq();
  }

  return len;
}
```

Before transmitting over UART it masks exceptions which can have a priority set via __disable_irq() (which I understand includes all peripheral and GPIO interrupts).

My question is, why is this UART tx implemented this way?
Can the disable/enable irq calls be removed so that other functionality in the program is not delayed due to potentially lengthy data transactions?

Comment: What exactly is "RETARGET"?  Is that some term specific to your application?  Do we need to know about that to answer this question?  Where did this code come from?

Comment: @DavidGrayson it probably means "redirecting". But I wonder where `stdout` should go without that. UART is probably the only way to implement `stdout` on a micro.

Comment: Sorry I should have elaborated. retarget basically allows us to use printf calls on our microcontroller, and read any output via a serial console as if we were reading from stdout. @Gerhardh is correct. The benefit of using printf instead of just a direct uart call, is we can run the same software on x86 (mocking out the hardware level) and have output sent to the console.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect the author of that code is disabling all interrupts just because there might be some interrupts that write bytes to the UART, and the author wants to ensure that all the bytes sent to the `_write` function get written consecutively, instead of having other, unrelated bytes in the middle.

I'm assuming all the ISRs defined in your system are relatively quick compared to the serial transmission, and the receiver doesn't care if there are some small delays in the transmission.  So it should be OK to leave any interrupts enabled if those interrupts are not related to the UART.

You should get a firm grasp of all the ISRs in your system and what they do, and then you should use that to decide which specific IRQs should be disabled during this operation (if any).

Answer (score 1):

It's a quasi-bad design.

For one thing, *always* calling `__disable_irq` but *not* `__enable_irq` is suspicious.

It prevents *nested* calls where the caller is *also* doing `__disable_irq/__enable_irq`.

It assumes that a Tx ISR is *not* involved. That is, the UART is running in polled mode. But, if *that* were true, why did the code disable/enable interrupts?

If there is more data to send to the UART Tx than can be put into the Tx FIFO, the code [as you've seen] will *block*.

This means that the base/task level can't do other things.

---

When I do such UART code, I use a ring queue. I define one that is large enough to accomodate any bursts (e.g. queue is 10,000).

The design assumes that if the `_write` is called and the ring queue becomes full before all data is added, the ring queue size should be increased (i.e. ring queue full is a [fatal] design error).

Otherwise, the base/task level is trying to send too much data. That is, it's generating more data than can be sent at the Tx baud rate.

The `_write` process:

1. Copy bytes to the ring queue.
2. Copy as many bytes from the queue to the UART as space in the UART Tx FIFO allows.
3. Tx ISR will be called if space becomes available. It repeats step (2)

With this, `_write` will *not* block if the UART Tx FIFO becomes full.

The Tx ISR will pick up the slack. That is, when there is more space available in the FIFO, and the Tx is "ready", the Tx ISR will be called.

---

Here is some pseudo code to illustrate what I mean:

```
// push_tx_data -- copy data from Tx ring queue into UART Tx FIFO
int
push_tx_data(void)
{

    // fill Tx FIFO with as much data as it can hold
    while (1) {
        // no free space in Tx FIFO
        if (USART_GetFlagStatus(RETARGET_CFG_UART, USART_FLAG_TXE) != RESET)
            break;

        // dequeue byte to transmit (stop if queue empty)
        int i = tx_queue_dequeue();
        if (i < 0)
            break;

        // put this data byte into the UART Tx FIFO
        uint8_t buf = i;
        USART_SendData(RETARGET_CFG_UART, buf);
    }
}

// tx_ISR -- handle interrupt from UART Tx
void
tx_ISR(void)
{

    // presumeably interrupts are already disabled in the ISR ...

    // copy all the data we can
    push_tx_data();

    // clear the interrupt pending flag in the interrupt controller or ISR if
    // necessary (i.e.) USART_SendData didn't clear it when the FIFO was full
}

// _write -- send data
int
_write(int fd, char *ptr, int len)
{
    uint32_t primask = __get_PRIMASK();

    // running from task level so disable interrupts
    if (! primask)
        __disable_irq();

    int sent = 0;

    // add to [S/W] tx ring queue
    for (int i = 0; i < len; i++) {
        if (! tx_queue_enqueue(ptr[i]))
            break;
        ++sent;
    }

    // send data from queue into FIFO
    push_tx_data();

    // reenable interrupts (task level)
    if (! primask)
        __enable_irq();

    return sent;
}
```

Comment: I think `__get_PRIMASK` is what you call to see if interrupts are disabled, so the OP's use if `__enable_irq` and `__disable_irq` is not suspicious, and nesting would work.  The OP's code doesn't use a TX ISR, but it would still work fine in a system that does have a TX ISR; the call to `_write` would just take over the UART for a while and write everything itself.  Having a `_write` function that returns without writing all the data is potentially annoying and error-prone, but I guess it's OK if it's only called in a few places and it is called carefully.

Comment: @DavidGrayson No, it breaks nesting. If the caller does: `disable(); do_receiver_stuff(); _write(...); do_more_stuff(); enable();` then `do_more_stuff` [which _expects_ interrupts disabled] would be called with them enabled. The code _does_ guarantee non-blocking behavior because as I mentioned above, it's _designed_ that way. If the ring queue fills up, that's a design error. The queue must be made large enough so that it can accomodate _whatever_ burst `_write` gives it. (e.g.) If 10,000 bytes isn't enough, use 20,000 ...

Comment: The end of the OP's code basically says: "if interrupts were not disabled when this function started, enable interrupts."  So `do_more_stuff` would run without interrupts.  That's a very broad generalization about blocking and buffer sizes; it depends on the application.

Comment: *No, it breaks nesting.* Why? I would say, it is done to allow nesting. If you unconditionally disable/enable then I would agree that nesting is broken. But that is not the case here. One might suggest to do the disabling under same condition but as it doesn't change anything if interrupts are already disabled, just disabling them might simply be faster than checking a condition.

Comment: @CraigEstey: Gerhardh and David are correct, the code is written specifically to avoid the problem you describe.  In fact this is pretty standard boilerplate used everywhere.  You have interpreted it as the exact opposite of what it does.  (The only possible problem is that reading PRIMASK and writing it is not atomic but there are ways to mitigate that).